# Solve for Y; don't understand Wolfram Alpha's solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, wolfram-alpha

Answering this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345621/converting-davenport-diagram/28352182#28352182), I needed to solve this equation in terms of y:

$$x = 6.1 + \log(\frac{{y}}{{0.03p}})$$

Doing it by hand:

$$y = 0.03p10^{{(x-6.1)}}$$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%3D%206.1%20%2B%20log10%28y%20%2F%20%280.03p%29%29%2C%20solve%20for%20y) tells me it's:

$$y = 3p10^{{(x-8.1)}}$$

How are these equivalent?

**EDITS**

So the how is pretty straightforward, but now the why.  Is this a simpler form of the equation or an artifact of Wolfram's processing?

Comment: $0.03\times 10^2 = 3$

Comment: Did you try to replace the two expressions for _y_ in the equation?

Comment: @BernardMassé, do you mean, did I test that both equations are equivalent?  Yes.

Comment: *Is this a simpler form of the equation or an artifact of Wolfram's processing?* I think most people would agree that an integer coefficient, $3$, is in some senses (aesthetic, intellectual, ...) better than $0.03$, all else being equal.

Comment: @Mark, if you tested both answers, you knew that your answer was good. To further reassure yourself, you could have either subtracted one answer from the other and after simplifying finding 0 or divided and verified that the result was 1.

Comment: @BernardMassé, thanks.  I was never concerned that one or the other was wrong, I was more interested in how/why wolfram took it the extra step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y=3p10^{x-8.1}=3p10^{x-6.1-2}=3p10^{x-6.1} 10^{-2}=0.03p10^{x-6.1}$.